# выбрать один checkbox из двух

Tags: html, jquery, css, checkbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Есть несколько `checkbox-ов`,нужно чтобы выбирался 1 или 2 `checkbox`, а остальные выбирались независимо от них. `id`, `name` не меняются так как используются в программе.

```js
$('#count').keyup(calculate);

function calculate() {
  if ($("#Bort").is(':checked')) sum += 1400;

  if ($("#Borta").is(':checked')) sum += 2800;
}

$('input.kartinki').on("click", function() {
  if ($('#Bort').prop('checked')) {
    $('#image').attr('src', 'img/kartinki_chekbox/belava/bl_l_310.jpg');
  } else if ($('#Borta').prop('checked')) {
    $('#image').attr('src', 'img/kartinki_chekbox/belava/bl_p_310.jpg');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="Bort">1</label>
<input class="kartinki" name="Борт" type="checkbox" id="Bort" />

<label for="Borta">2</label>
<input class="kartinki" name="Борта" type="checkbox" id="Borta" />

<label for="morilka">3</label>
<input name="Морилка" type="checkbox" id="morilka" />
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит вопрос описать более подробно...

Comment: @Air а что именно добавить?

Comment: А почему не использовать для 1 и 2 радио? И пользователю понятнее.

Comment: Лиана,  `нужно чтобы выбирался 1 или 2 checkbox, а остальные выбирались независимо от них. id` - это кусок из вопроса, который я не совсем понял

Comment: И согласен с @ArtemGorlachev, почему тогда первые два не `type="radio"`?

Comment: поправила код,посмотрите

Comment: они считают сумму и при нажатии появляется соответсвующая картинка

Comment: @Лиана, всеравно намного проще будет с событием `change` используя `type="radio"`. А вообще вам просто надо в вашем коде снимать выделение - `$('#Borta').prop('checked', false)`

Comment: @ Artem Gorlachev я бы с удовольствием их поменяла на радио и не парилась))посмотрите картинку добавила,по заданию они все chekcbox

Comment: Лиана, используй `type="radio"`, но при этом привяжи их к `checkbox-су`, будет или тот или тот... А `type="radio"` задай `display: none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Снимайте галку со второго чекбокса, когда кликаете в первый, и наоборот.

```js
$('input.kartinki').on("click", function() {

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(id == 'Bort' || id == 'Borta'){
    
        var img = {'Bort' : "bl_l_310.jpg'", 'Borta': "bl_p_310.jpg"};
        
        if($(this).prop('checked')){        
            var uncheck = id == 'Bort' ? '#Borta' : '#Bort';
            $(uncheck).prop('checked', false);
        }        
        
        $("#image").attr('src', "img/kartinki_chekbox/belava" + img[id]);  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="Bort">1</label>
<input class="kartinki" name="Борт" type="checkbox" id="Bort" />

<label for="Borta">2</label>
<input class="kartinki" name="Борта" type="checkbox" id="Borta" />

<label for="morilka">3</label>
<input name="Морилка" type="checkbox" id="morilka" />
```

Comment: попробовала без ссылок на картинки просто на выбор чекбоксов-не получается в главном коде

Comment: @Лиана не видя кода особо ничего не подскажешь.

Comment: код очень большои. Вот так же используя id: id="Bort", id="Borta"  что бы ставилась галочка на 1 или 2